# Unable to record Android native app requests in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, android

I have followed the steps given in article http://www.testingdiaries.com/mobile-performance-testing-record-script-jmeter/

I set manual proxy in phone and started the recorder but none of my requests are recorded. Will this method really work? I wanted to perform load testing on my native app (mostly the sign-in scenario) Please take a look and let me know.
I know blazemeter support recording and perform load test but I prefer working only with Jmeter

Comment: Does your phone and desktop share the same network ? are you sure you entered the right addresses ? can you see the web from your phone ?

Comment: Yes. Both are connected to same wifi network. Additionally I set manual proxy in phone under Wifi Network > Advanced options.
Proxy hostname: IP (my external IP) set in Jmeter HTTPS Domain and 8080 port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be the case your application talks to backend using SSL, in that case some extra tweaks may be required:

1. Android network configuration tool won't proxy SSL connections so you may have to use 3rd party tool like [ProxyDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.proxydroid&hl=en) for setting it up. Not sure about iOS devices, I don't have any.
2. You'll need to install JMeter's self-signed certificate on the device. Locate `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` file in /bin folder of your JMeter installation (it is generated when you start JMeter's proxy first time) and deliver it somehow to the device, i.e. send yourself a mail message with the certificate attached.

The easier way is using [Mobile Recorder](https://docs.blazemeter.com/customer/portal/articles/1946705-mobile-recorder) service which provides simple interface where you can download [MITM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) certificate in order to be able to record secure traffic, inspect requests and export them as JMeter JMX file.

Comment: Dmitri - I followed all steps given on Blazemeter blog. Created proxy using http://a.blazemeter.com/app/recorder/index.html Then configured all proxy host and port in Real Mobile Android device. Installed mitm crt file in mobile then started recording. Then in mobile i was started navigating to app but nothing happens then i navigate using samsung browser to google.com it is getting recorded. It is not able to detect any of the app navigation.

Comment: If you're using [Android 6.0 or higher you will also need to introduce some changes](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/07/changes-to-trusted-certificate.html) into the application you're trying to record, check out [Recording Using Android Devices](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000285357-Recording-Using-Android-Devices) article for exact steps if needed.